# Recording terminal input and logs in VS Code extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, console, vscode-extensions

I want to create an extension that can access the command line input of a workspace terminal. I also want to record the various logs that occur within that console as well. I have looked at the extension API but haven't found anything useful. How would one go about doing this?